# Convert This Left-Join SQL to Method Syntax Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need the equivalent of this SQL statement in Linq, using method/fluent syntax.

```
SELECT u.[UserId], s.[UserId], d.[UserId]
FROM dbo.[Attachment] z  
INNER JOIN dbo.[Activity] a ON z.[ActivityId] = a.[ActivityId]
INNER JOIN dbo.[Case] c ON a.[CaseId] = c.[CaseId]
INNER JOIN dbo.[CaseUser] x ON c.[CaseId] = x.[CaseId]
INNER JOIN dbo.[User] u ON x.[UserId] = u.[UserId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[User] s ON u.[SupervisorId] = s.[UserId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[User] d ON s.[SupervisorId] = d.[UserId]
WHERE u.[UserId] = @x OR s.[UserId] = @x OR d.[UserId] = @x
```

Also, I use it in a context where I must return a System.Linq.Expressions.Expression object. For example, an example of existing, simpler code would be:

```
public override Expression<Func<Attachment, bool>> MatchingCriteria
{
  get { return a => a.Activity.Case.CaseUsers.Any(x => (x.User.Id == this.id)); }
}
```

I am stumped by the left joins using method syntax that evaluates to a bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work... You check to make sure the related entity in the model is not null and then do a comparison if it is not:

```
return a => a.Activity.Case.CaseUsers
    .Where(cu => cu.User.Id == this.id || 
           (cu.User.Supervisor != null && 
            cu.User.Supervisor.Id == this.Id) || 
           (cu.User.Supervisor != null && 
            cu.User.Supervisor.Supervisor != null && 
            cu.User.Supervisor.Supervisor.Id == this.Id));
```

Comment: Note that this is not a join and hence, the right user is not returned.

Comment: Well, I replaced the WHERE with an ANY, since I am testing essentially for existence of the UserId along the user chain. It seems to work, but will test more. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I wrote that query assuming he did not want to return a user.  I'm pretty sure the generated SQL should roughly match his query, but you'd have to use ToTraceString() or Profiler to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following method, you can both check if either one of the required Id's exist and select the item.

With a sample class definition like:

```
class Foo
{
    public int FirstBarId { get; set; }

    public int SecondBarId { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
}
```

You can query like:

```
var query = fooSet.Select(foo => new
                    {
                        Foo = foo,
                        Bar1 = barSet.FirstOrDefault(bar => foo.FirstBarId == bar.BarId),
                        Bar2 = barSet.FirstOrDefault(bar => foo.SecondBarId == bar.BarId)
                    })
                    .Where(x => x.Bar1 != null || x.Bar2 != null);
```

Comment: Actually, the class in question is a recursive one: class User { public User Supervisor {get; set;} }

Comment: @alphadogg - That doesn't change a thing :)

Comment: Wouldn't it? I mean you have two "independent" Bar children to Foo, whereas my issue is how to walk down multiple levels of children?

Comment: @alphadogg - Walking down multiple levels is just that. You can easily expand the query I provided. Where do you think, is the difference when replacing barSet with fooSet?